# Add index in pandas based on each occurance of another column specific value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have a dataframe like so:

```
category name   age 
parent  harry   29
child   smith   12
parent  sally   41
child   david   19
child   mike    16
```

And I want to add a column to group families based on each occurence of category column value 'parent' (the dataframe is in order). As in:

```
category name   age  family_id
parent  harry   29     0
child   smith   12     0
parent  sally   41     1
child   david   19     1
child   mike    16     1
```

I am trying to make the family_id be an incrementing integer.

I've tried a bunch of group_by and am currently trying to write my own apply function but its very slow and not working as expected. I haven't been able to find an example that groups rows based on a column value *over every occurence of the* **same** *value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) to match if `category` column equals `parent` and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) , [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) is to subtract 1 since cumsum starts from 1 here:

```
df['family_id'] = df['category'].eq('parent').cumsum().sub(1)
print(df)
```

---

```
  category   name  age  family_id
0   parent  harry   29          0
1    child  smith   12          0
2   parent  sally   41          1
3    child  david   19          1
4    child   mike   16          1
```

Comment: @sawezo there is almost all solutions without iterating over a dataframe in pandas. Of course there can be some edge cases but try to search for a vectorized one . :)

Comment: If I wanted to add an additional column off of family_id named person_id (within a single family), any suggestions? Im thinking something like df["person_id"] = df["family_id"].eq(somehow test for a new integer).cumsum().sub(1)

Comment: @sawezo sorry i didnt get your question

Comment: row 1: ```category   name  age  family_id person_id```
row 2:```0   parent  harry   29          0            0```
row 3: ```1    child  smith   12          0             1```
row 4:```2   parent  sally   41          1            0```
```3    child  david   19          1             1```
```4    child   mike   16          1             2```

Comment: something like that to continue with the same example... so there is a new column that does the same idea as family_id did but now within a single family

Comment: @sawezo can you try : `df['new_id'] = df.groupby(df['category'].eq('parent').cumsum()).cumcount()`